# Unable to delete file using file.delete()

Tags: java

I'm unable to delete my file, i have looked here but can't find the answer.
i have rights to delete,files,the files exist.Below is a class which contains a method delete file

```
public boolean deleteFile(String filePath)
    {

            File fileToDelete = new File(filePath);
            System.out.println("In delete file(): "+fileToDelete.exists());
            boolean deleted = fileToDelete.delete();
            return deleted;

    }
```

and i have a button that have a action listener to delete a file based on a CONSTANT string file path.

```
STFile file = new STFile();
System.out.println("Deleting from"+STMain.TITLES_PATH+""+file.deleteFile(STMain.TITLES_PATH));


public static final String TITLES_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\titlesPath.txt";
    public static final String IMAGES_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\imagesPath.txt";
    public static final String SOUNDS_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\soundPath.txt";
```

the files exists and the directory exists, may i know what is preventing me from deleting them?
is it because i have a fileoutputstream?but i have them closed,btw the qnsTitle,qnsImagePath,qnsSoundPath are all arraylists containing strings.

```
public void writeFiles()
    {
        FileOutputStream f_out = null;
        ObjectOutputStream obj_out = null;
        try {
            f_out = new FileOutputStream(STMain.TITLES_PATH);
            obj_out = new ObjectOutputStream (f_out);
            obj_out.writeObject(qnsTitle);
            f_out.close();
            f_out = new FileOutputStream(STMain.IMAGES_PATH);
            obj_out = new ObjectOutputStream (f_out);
            obj_out.writeObject(qnsImagePath);
            f_out.close();
            f_out = new FileOutputStream(STMain.SOUNDS_PATH);
            obj_out = new ObjectOutputStream (f_out);
            obj_out.writeObject(qnsSoundPath);
            f_out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may not have permission to modify contents of the directory containing files. Do you have write permission on the directory? Can you please create the directory object with `File` class and check for `isWritable()`? And please give the exception here so that we can figure out the problem.

Comment: What is answer of STMain.TITLESPATH means which path does it shows. Can you paste the path here?

Comment: there is no exception thrown when i run the method, it just keeps returning a false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your writeFiles() method, write the close() in a finally block so you are guaranteed that it is executed.

Comment: thanks, other than writeFiles i also have a readFile method which reads the files, and in that method i didnt close them, that should be why im not able to delete them.